# How to use Jasmine to test if an instance is created?

Tags: requirejs, jasmine

Hi Am new to using Jasmine. The issue is as follows: I have a number of modules, managed through RequireJS. Now a module A creates an instance of another module B in it. Is it possible to use Jasmine to test whether an instance of B is being created in A? To convey a clearer idea of the code, we have:

```
             //In module A 
             define(['B',],function(B){
                 function test(){
                    var newTest = new B();
                 };
                 return {test: test};
              });
```

Now, how do i use Jasmine to test that module A indeed, creates an instance of module B? Thanks in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to check the type of an object in a Jasmine test:

```
describe('ChocolateFactory', function() {
    it('creates an instance of Chocolate', function() {
        var factory = new ChocolateFactory();
        var chocolate = factory.makeChocolate();
        expect(chocolate instanceof Chocolate).toBe(true);
    });
});
```