# Testing for instanceof using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I'm new to Jasmine and testing in general. One block of my code checks whether my library has been instantiated using the new operator:

```
 //if 'this' isn't an instance of mylib...
 if (!(this instanceof mylib)) {
     //return a new instance
     return new mylib();   
 }
```

How can I test this using Jasmine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Jasmine to test if an instance is created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062034/how-to-use-jasmine-to-test-if-an-instance-is-created)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jasmine uses matchers to do its assertions, so you can write your own custom matcher to check anything you want, including an instanceof check. https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Matchers

In particular, check out the Writing New Matchers section.

Answer (score 130):

#### Jasmine >=3.5.0

Jasmine provides the [`toBeInstanceOf`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html) matcher.

```
it("matches any value", () => {
  expect(3).toBeInstanceOf(Number);
});
```

#### Jasmine >2.3.0

To check if something is an `instanceof [Object]` Jasmine provides [`jasmine.any`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Matching_Anything_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.any%3C/code%3E):

```
it("matches any value", function() {
  expect({}).toEqual(jasmine.any(Object));
  expect(12).toEqual(jasmine.any(Number));
});
```

Comment: Property 'toBeInstanceOf' does not exist on type 'ArrayLikeMatchers<string>'

Answer (score 35):

I do prefer the more readable/intuitive (in my opinion) use with the [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator.

```
class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent {}

let c = new Child();

expect(c instanceof Child).toBeTruthy();
expect(c instanceof Parent).toBeTruthy();
```

For the sake of completeness you can also use the prototype `constructor` property in some cases.

```
expect(my_var_1.constructor).toBe(Array);
expect(my_var_2.constructor).toBe(Object);
expect(my_var_3.constructor).toBe(Error);

// ...
```

**BEWARE** that this won't work if you need to check whether an object inherited from another or not.

```
class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent {}

let c = new Child();

console.log(c.constructor === Child); // prints "true"
console.log(c.constructor === Parent); // prints "false"
```

If you need inheritance support definitely use the `instanceof` operator or the [jasmine.any()](https://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Matching_Anything_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.any%3C/code%3E) function like **Roger** suggested.

[Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) reference.

Comment: What if you want explicitly check if c is of type Child? That is, it should fail if it's of its parent type. Is there a way to test this other than doing something like constructor.name?

Comment: I think I reported examples already in my answer for that, both with the `instanceof` operator and with `c.constructor === Child`.